# Adding/Removing a pane from kendo splitter at runtime

Tags: kendo-ui, addition, splitter, pane

I want to be able add a new pane/ remove an exiting pane from a kendo splitter without reloading other remaining panes. Is it possible with kendo splitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not supported. All the methods the Splitter has are covered [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/splitter) and there is no such method which allows you to insert/remove panes. You need to re-initiailze the whole Splitter.

Comment: Thanks Petur! This confirms what I was suspecting.

Comment: BTW are there any particular reasons why something like this is not supported? I would expect this to be a common requirement.

Comment: No particular reason, it is just not implemented. Give an idea on our official feedback portal. If more people vote for it we can consider implementing it.
http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback

Comment: Thanks Petur! I searched the existing feedbacks on the portal and found these ones similar to my requirements: http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/2606435-offer-the-possibility-to-remove-a-panel
http://feedback.kendoui.com/forums/127393-kendo-ui-feedback/suggestions/3528537-offer-the-possibility-to-add-a-panel
. I have increased the votes for both.